# Why is Loading from an XML File in OpenCV Corrupting my Data?

Tags: c, xml, image, opencv

The problem I seem to be having is that when I load IplImgaes stored as xml files, some of the data members associated with the IplImage object are corrupted. For example d1->width should be 1024 and d1->height should be 768. Instead, it seems that regardless of the way in which I load these images I get garbage values like -72538984, -1272467456, and 0. I have also tested d1->depth and d1->nChannels which hold simmilar garbage values. I am using the OpenCV C API xml persistence to write and read these images to and from the disk. I have read and reread the relavent documentation to make sure that I am using the API correctly, but it seems that regardless of how I read the images there is still some form of data loss or corruption.

The reason I am using xml persistence is when I used the function cvSaveImage in the program that takes the images, the function would truncate the data from a 16 to an 8 bit format. It is my understanding that using xml persistence will avoid this problem. Also, I am trying to avoid using the C++ API for this project as it is an extension of prior work already written using the C API. Based on the code I have included below, can I be sure that I am doing this part correctly and that the problem lies elsewhere in the process of image creation, storage, retreival, and use? Or is there something I am doing here that is patently wrong? Thank you very much for your help.

Approach 1

```
CvFileStorage * fs1 = cvOpenFileStorage("/home/bot/luca-HSV/HSVD/GRID1/SQUARE4/DEPTH180.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ); 
CvFileStorage * fs2 = cvOpenFileStorage("/home/bot/luca-HSV/HSVD/GRID1/SQUARE4/DEPTH144.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ);

d1 = (IplImage*) cvReadByName(fs1, 0, "depthImage");
d2 = (IplImage*) cvReadByName(fs2, 0, "depthImage");

cvReleaseFileStorage(&fs1);
cvReleaseFileStorage(&fs2);
```

Approach 2

```
CvFileStorage * fs1 = cvOpenFileStorage("/home/bot/luca-HSV/HSVD/GRID1/SQUARE4/DEPTH180.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ); 
CvFileStorage * fs2 = cvOpenFileStorage("/home/bot/luca-HSV/HSVD/GRID1/SQUARE4/DEPTH144.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ);

CvFileNode * node1 = cvGetFileNodeByName(fs1, 0, "depthImage");
CvFileNode * node2 = cvGetFileNodeByName(fs2, 0, "depthImage");

d1 = (IplImage*) cvRead(fs1, node1);
d2 = (IplImage*) cvRead(fs2, node2);

cvReleaseFileStorage(&fs1);
cvReleaseFileStorage(&fs2);
```

Approach 3

```
d1 = (IplImage*) cvLoad("/home/bot/luca-HSV/HSVD/GRID1/SQUARE4/DEPTH180.xml"/*, NULL, NULL, NULL*/);
d2 = (IplImage*) cvLoad("/home/bot/luca-HSV/HSVD/GRID1/SQUARE4/DEPTH144.xml"/*, NULL, NULL, NULL*/);
// I have tried both using and not using these three NULL parameters. It
// does not seem to make a lot of difference
```

Before all of these methods I include the following lines:

```
IplImage * d1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT), IPL_DEPTH_64F, 3);
IplImage * d2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT), IPL_DEPTH_64F, 3);
```

Sample XML file Header

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<depthImage type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>768</rows>
  <cols>1024</cols>
  <dt>"3d"</dt>
  <data>
```

Comment: I believe the imwrite function of the C++ API only allows 16 bit unsigned, and I need to be able to hold negative values.

Comment: Can somebody please explain why my question has been voted down? I provided exhaustive details from every angle of the problem of which I could think without including a bunch of unnecessary code. The core problem is also stated clearly in the first line of the question with relevant details provided following. How is this question not clear or well researched?

Comment: I agree, the question is well presented: +1. Take a look at the answer and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you xml file, you saved a `CvMat` (`type_id="opencv-matrix"`), not an `IplImage` (`type_id="opencv-image"`).

So when you're loading it, you should cast to `CvMat*`, or you'll get garbage values.

For example, this will work:

```
CvFileStorage* fs = cvOpenFileStorage("path_to_xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ);
CvMat* img = (CvMat*)cvReadByName(fs, NULL, "depthImage", NULL);
cvReleaseFileStorage(&fs);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I actually just figured it out a few minutes ago. I was (somewhat embarrasingly) mixing up C++ and C API calls in the program that generated images. Your solution would likely have worked as well since using the C++ API call for writing structures seems to not have been enterly compatible with the IplImage type as it was saving the file with type_id="opencv-matrix". Now it is "opencv-image". I guess they really want people to switch over to the new version. Really, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad you made it work. C api is deprecated, if you can switch to C++, it'll be much better